# How to hang ceiling hooks with double layered drywal?

Tags: ceiling, drywall-anchor

I tried a cheap plastic anchor first and it wouldn’t screw in completely then broke. I switched to metal toggle bolts and they weren’t going in enough to open. I realized there are two layers of drywall with a very small space between. It’s not enough room for the toggle to open between the layers, and the two layers together are a good inch and a half deep. What are my options?
Thanks,
Krista

Comment: First need to know what you want to hang and how heavy it is.  Do not want a heavy weight above your head with weak anchors or in weak material.  Inch and a half quite a bit for ceilings.  With a space in between, just wondering if they used 1x wood to hold the second layer.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the plastic anchor broke? 1 or 2 layers of drywall will make no difference for installing one of those. Depending on the problem you ran in to, you may not have drilled a large enough hole for the anchor, or the surface behind it a harder material (stud, masonry). Depending on the type of metal anchor you used, they may assume a single drywall layer and you would have an issue.

Comment: Get a toggle with a longer threaded portion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Find a joist and screw your hooks directly into that.

Comment: Sounds like it could be metal furring attached to concrete. Try *not* cheap plastic anchors, *not* near a 'joist'. If it is wood frame, then "find a joist", +1. (you may have to clip or grind off the 'drill' tip of a *metal* drywall screw-in anchor, and cut the screw that goes in it)

Comment: Are your floors and ceilings concrete?

Comment: Thanks  to everyone who answered and to Solar Mike for the simple solution I needed. A longer screw allowed me to get the toggle above both layers of drywall so it could open.

Answer (score 1):

When I have thick walls I use zip toggles sometimes called snap toggler, or toggler brand. These have flexible connections to the toggle.

Drill A 1/4” hole (depending on the one chosen) stuff it through pull back then zip or snap and the toggle is held in place (the metal piece with the threads) these are as strong as all metal toggles and stronger than most Molly bolts but easier to use in my opinion (at least for over head work).

some think the metal shafts are stronger but the toggle itself and the screw that it connects to is where the holding force comes from.